# Poner fecha en JDateChooser JAVA

Tags: java

Cómo pongo una fecha consultada en un JDateChooser (JAVA)? He intentado darle formato de varias formas pero no lo consigo... **NOTA**: Tengo la fecha en una cadena con formato (*yyyy/MM/dd*)

Comment: podrías agregar lo que hiciste para poder ayudarte. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código es sencillo y con una simple búsqueda deberías haberlo encontrado, al menos en inglés. Lo que necesitas es esto:

```
java.util.Date fechaParseada= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(tuFecha);
jDateChooser.setDate(fechaParseada);
```

Answer (score 0):

He tardado en ver sus comentarios a falta de acceso a la red y lo único que se me ocurrió fue obtener la fecha formateada directamente de la consulta... Ya lo he dejado así pero intentaré sus propuestas gracias!

Comment: Hola Jose. No veo claro por que esta es la respuesta aceptada. No lo veo como respuesta directamente. Podrias elaborar un poco? un saludo.

Comment: Una disculpa y claro, lo que hice fue obtener el campo de fecha directamente formateado a manera que lo pueda ingresar directamente en el JDateChooser de esta forma: date_format(fecha, "%d-%m-%Y") //Esto usando mysql